# Why is the dialog design inconsistent on the device?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I designed dialog and assigned it a file named XML layout with a set of elements and then created a function to show it from within fragment. It appeared on the emulator screen well but it did not appear the same on the device.

What are the appropriate adjustments to be shown on the device well?

[image]

```
// layout xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f71717">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_layout"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText">
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioSex"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/second2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:textDirection="rtl"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:text="رفض"

                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,SpUsage" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:textDirection="rtl"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:text="قبول"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,SpUsage" />
            </RadioGroup>
            />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="وقت التسليم"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/tex"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:popupBackground="#fff78c"
            style="@style/spinner_style"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry,SpUsage"
            android:entries="@array/day_"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="129dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/l_layout"
        android:background="#f71717"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_h"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner_minutes2"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="ساعة"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_m"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spinner_minutes2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner_minutes2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_holder"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="دق"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spinner_minutes"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner_minutes"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner_minutes3"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="ص/م"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_minutes"
            android:layout_width="85dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            style="@style/spinner_style"
            android:popupBackground="#fff78c"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner_minutes2"
            android:entries="@array/hour_" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_minutes2"
            android:layout_width="85dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_minutes"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:popupBackground="#fff78c"
            style="@style/spinner_style"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_m"
            android:entries="@array/hour_" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_minutes3"
            android:layout_width="85dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/spinner_style"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:entries="@array/apm"
            android:popupBackground="#fff78c"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spinner_minutes2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner_minutes2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner_minutes" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_holder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_minutes"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_set"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="الغاء"
                tools:ignore="ButtonStyle,HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:text="إرسال"
                tools:ignore="ButtonOrder,ButtonStyle,HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>


//calss  Fragment:


public class Page_6Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    TextView t1,t2,t3,t4;
    Spinner spin ,spin2,spin3,spin4;
    Dialog dialog;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Customer> customers;
    CustomerAdapter adapter;
    View rootView;
    String TAG = "MainActivity - ";
    Context context;
    API api;
    Activity a;

    public static Page_6Fragment newInstance() {
        Page_6Fragment fragment = new Page_6Fragment();
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customer, container, false);
        //   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.xml.pref, container, false);
        //  Intent intent = new Intent(PreferenceDemoActivity.this,PrefsActivity.class);
        // startActivity(intent);

        this.context = getActivity();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        customers = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CustomerAdapter(context, customers);

        adapter.setLoadMoreListener(new CustomerAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener(){
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int index = customers.size() - 1;
                      loadMore(index);
                    }
                });
                //Calling loadMore function in Runnable to fix the
                // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling error
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        //recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalLineDecorator(2));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        api = ServiceGenerator.createService(API.class);
        load(0);
        return rootView;
    }
    private void load(int index){
        Call<List<Customer>> call = api.getCustomer(index);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Customer>>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Customer>> call, Response<List<Customer>> response){
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "tost "+response.body().get(0).post_writer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // Log.i("TRUE_TRUE","Yes"+response.body().get(0).title);
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    customers.addAll(response.body());
                    adapter.notifyDataChanged();
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tost "+response.body().get(0).post_writer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG," Response Error "+String.valueOf(response.code()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Customer>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG," Response Error "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadMore(int index){
        //add loading progress view
        customers.add(new Customer("load"));
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(customers.size()-1);
        Call<List<Customer>>call =  api.getCustomer(index);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Customer>>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Customer>> call, Response<List<Customer>>response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    // remove loading view .......
                    customers.remove(customers.size()-1);
                    List<Customer>result=response.body();
                    if(result.size()>0){
                        // add loaded data
                        customers.addAll(result);
                    }else{//result size 0 means there is no more data available at server
                        adapter.setMoreDataAvailable(false);
                        //telling adapter to stop calling load more as no more server data available
                        Toast.makeText(context,"No More Data Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataChanged();
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG," Load More Response Error "+String.valueOf(response.code()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Customer>>call,Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG," Load More Response Error "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public void showDialog(Context context){
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        dialog.show();

        String[] bankNames = {
                "BO","SB","HD","PN","Bj"
        };
        t1= (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_h);
        t2= (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_m);
        t3= (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        t4= (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_pam);
        spin =(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_minutes);
        spin2 =(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_minutes2);
        spin3 =(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_minutes3);
        spin4 =(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tex);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.second2);
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.second);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.spinner_item,bankNames);
        //ArrayAdapter b = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,bankNames2);
        a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(a);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(checkedId);
                if (checkedId == R.id.second2) {
                    RadioYes();
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.second) {
                   RadioNo();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(16);
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" +spin2.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    public void  RadioNo(){
        spin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spin2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spin3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spin4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        t1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        t3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        t4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void  RadioYes(){
        spin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spin2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spin3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spin4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        t2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        t3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        t4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

// class to call function show dailoge 


public class CustomerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public final int TYPE_MOVIE = 0;
    public final int TYPE_LOAD = 1;

    static Context context;
    List<Customer> customers;
    OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener;
    boolean isLoading = false, isMoreDataAvailable = true;

    public CustomerAdapter(Context context, List<Customer> customers) {
        this.context = context;
        this.customers = customers;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if(viewType==TYPE_MOVIE){
            return new CustomerHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_movie,parent,false));
        }else{
            return new LoadHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_load,parent,false));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if(position>=getItemCount()-1 && isMoreDataAvailable && !isLoading && loadMoreListener!=null){
            isLoading = true;
            loadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
        }

        if(getItemViewType(position)==TYPE_MOVIE){
            ((CustomerHolder)holder).bindData(customers.get(position));
            if(((CustomerHolder)holder).buttonViewOption != null)((CustomerHolder)holder).buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  Page_6Fragment.newInstance().showDialog(context);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(customers.get(position).type.equals("movie")){
            return TYPE_MOVIE;
        }else{
            return TYPE_LOAD;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){

        return customers.size();
    }

    /* VIEW HOLDERS */

    static class CustomerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvRating;
        Button buttonViewOption;

        public CustomerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTitle=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            tvRating=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            buttonViewOption = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
        }

        void bindData(Customer cust){
           tvTitle.setText(cust.name);
           tvRating.setText(cust.title);
        }
    }

    static class LoadHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public LoadHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public void setMoreDataAvailable(boolean moreDataAvailable) {
        isMoreDataAvailable = moreDataAvailable;
    }

    /* notifyDataSetChanged is final method so we can't override it
         call adapter.notifyDataChanged(); after update the list
    */

    public void notifyDataChanged(){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        isLoading = false;
    }
    public interface OnLoadMoreListener{
        void onLoadMore();
    }
    public void setLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener) {
        this.loadMoreListener = loadMoreListener;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dialog dimensions aren't the same across devices. Your root LinearLayout should be using `match_parent` instead of `260dp`.

Comment: I made the adjustment. The white side was removed, but the top white color wasn't removed.

Comment: Both dimensions need to be `match_parent`.

Comment: Yes, I did the two, but there's still a white part in the top of the picture.

Comment: have you tried in any other physical devices ?

Comment: Thank you k, i remove title from the dialoge :        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
// Now every thing is well

Comment: Another thing you might want to do is:  

getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

On older devices you sometimes have that, if your dialog has rounded corners for example, then white corners show behind the rounded corners. This helps